# website.com auto direct to index.php

Tags: java, php, google-app-engine

I have a website running on google app engine written in php. So when a user lands on domain.com they get a 404 error as there is no index.html file just a index.php file.

Are there some sensible options to address this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Update `welcome-file-list` in your `web.xml` to include `index.php` file.